# .htaccess 301 redirect after trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this has been asked so many times before but I coulnd't find this particular script.

So I've started a franchise, and I've moved my www.site.com to shop1.site.com (shop2.site.com also exists.)

Google seems confused by the new setup so this is what I need

If someone goes to a url containing a directory after the trailing slash, I need to redirected to the new site with a 301

If not, leave it be

For example:

`www.site.com/info/ -> shop1.site.com/info/`

`www.site.com/help/ -> shop1.site.com/help/`

`www.site.com (leave as is)`

So basically any url with a directory, redirect, otherwise leave it be

## Update

here is my current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/.*)$ http://shop.site.com/$1` would work for any `www.site.com/xxx/` and possible subfolders. Still, I'm not sure reading your requirements if it has to be *real* folders or not

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Basically I need: If there's anything after the trailing slash, replace `www.site.com` with `shop1.site.com`

If the user goes directly to `www.site.com`, let them

A 404 doesn't really matter, that's fine as it'll take them to the shop1 404 page

Comment: Ok, so what I gave you above should do the trick

Comment: Great, thank you for your help! Add it an an answer and I'll mark as correct

Comment: One more question: do `www` and `shop1` share the same document root folder ? I mean, when you access one or the other, do you land on the same page (and so, the same htaccess) ?

Comment: Ok, [this happened](https://gbg.vr-world.se/avboka/)

My current .htaccess file is:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/.*)$ https://gbg.vr-world.se/$1



ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

ErrorDocument 500 /index.php`

Comment: I'm no DNS or server expert, but basically, my server shop1.site.com IS site.com/shop1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176945/discussion-between-richard-muthwill-and-justin-iurman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed. This redirects every page except for the root. Be warned, this also redirect's all traffic to HTTP and not HTTPS

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite everything except root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://shop1.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```